# On moving a parbox generated by p{width} to the very right in a tabular

Tags: tables, alignment, parbox

Let us focus on the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}
{|l|
r@{}@{\hspace{0.3em}}
|l|r|}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\textbf{(2)}
&$x$
&$=a+b+c+d+e$
&Putting some reasons here\\ 
\hline
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\textbf{(4)}
&\multicolumn{2}{p{5cm}}{Some multi lines sentences here.
            Some multi lines sentences here.}\vline
& \multicolumn{1}{p{2.5cm}}{I love to move this parbox to very right of the table, that will 
be great}\vline\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It creates a table as below:

[image]

I like to move the parbox to the very right to remove the yellow space, do u know how?

Comment: Probably you want to use `tabularx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand the same thing as Zarko (and I'm much slower).

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document} 

    \begin{tblr}
        {
        hlines,vlines,
        colspec = {
                    Q[c,m,wd=1.5em,font=\bfseries]
                    Q[l]
                    Q[l]
                    Q[r]},
        cell{2}{2}={c=2}{l}
        }
        %\mycnt
        (2)
        &$x$
        &$=a+b+c+d+e$
        &Putting some reasons here\\
        (4)
        &{Some multi lines sentences here.\\
        Some multi lines sentences here.}
        && \parbox[t]{2.5cm}{I love to move this parbox to very right of the table, that will 
        be great}
    \end{tblr}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear, what is the width of the last table column:

- 2.5 cm as can be concluded from `\multicolumn{1}{p{2.5cm}}{...}`  in your MWE, or
- the last two columns can have equal width

So, below are examples for the both cases, used `tabular˛,` tabularx`and`tblr`(defined in`tabularray` package) tables:

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabularray,
            tabularx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{The case when width of the last column is 2,5 cm}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|l| p{5cm} | p{2.5cm}|}
\textbf{(2)}    & $x=a+b+c+d+e$ & Putting some reasons here \\
    \hline
\textbf{(4)}    & Some multi lines sentences here.
            Some multi lines sentences here.
                & I love to move this parbox to very right of the table, that will be great
\end{tabular}

\medskip
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l, font=\bfseries] Q[l, 5cm] Q[l, 2.5cm]},
             vlines}
(2) & $x=a+b+c+d+e$ & Putting some reasons here \\
    \hline
(4) & Some multi lines sentences here.
      Some multi lines sentences here.
                    & I love to move this parbox to very right of the table, that will be great
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{The case when the last two columns have equal width}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l| X | X |}
\textbf{(2)}    & $x=a+b+c+d+e$ & Putting some reasons here \\
    \hline
\textbf{(4)}    & Some multi lines sentences here.
            Some multi lines sentences here.
                & I love to move this parbox to very right of the table, that will be great
\end{tabularx}

\medskip
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l, font=\bfseries] X[l] X[l]},
             vlines}
(2) & $x=a+b+c+d+e$ & Putting some reasons here \\
    \hline
(4) & Some multi lines sentences here.
      Some multi lines sentences here.
                    & I love to move this parbox to very right of the table, that will be great
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the `\multicolumn`. It's easier split a single cell then merge in all other columns; the solution uses inner `array`. Then, it is also easier to defined paragraph columns `p{}` which automatically add line breaks

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\bgroup
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| l | p{5cm} | p{4cm} |}
  \textbf{(2)}
    & \(\begin{array}{@{}r|l@{}}x & = a + b + c + d + e\end{array}\)
    & Putting some reasons here \\
  \hline
  \textbf{(4)}
    & Some multi lines sentences here. Some multi lines sentences here.
    & I love to move this parbox to very right of the table, that will be great} \\
\end{tabular}
\par
\egroup
\end{document}
```